# Uses of complex analysis in Dynamical systems

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems

I'm learning complex analysis and I was wondering if it has any direct conections with dynamical systems. So far I've seen one: The Ruelle zeta function. I would be very greatful if anyone could provide me with other relations between these fields.

Comment: Google? [search 1](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22dynamical+systems%22+%22complex+valued%22&filter=0) and [search 2](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22dynamical+systems%22+%22complex+number%22&filter=0) and [search 3](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22dynamical+systems%22+%22complex+analysis%22&filter=0)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_dynamics

Answer (score 1):

In general, the study of differential equations or recursion relations are central to dynamical systems (whether they are stochastic or deterministic).

Several integral transforms are used to solve those differential equations, like Fourier transforms or Laplace transforms, and in the case of recursion relations, we often use generating functions. Finally, in order to be able to invert these transforms, tools from complex analysis are often very useful - have a look at [Mellin inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_inversion_theorem).